# How to create a user password with an expiration date in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, authentication

I'm working with WindowsForms and C#. The deal of my project is that i need to set a password per user (there are currently 4 users) that expires in a month and after that they need to generate a new random password.
The part of the random password i already have it, but i can't make the expiration time to work.
I have been working with the DateTime class, but i cant make it to work.
I try to make an if condition like the example below:

```
if(DateTime.Now < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-10))
{
//Message box that tells you that the password has expired
}
else
{
//Random password generator code
}
```

Also i have try comparing seconds with a variable i define, example:

```
int Time = DateTime.Now.Seconds;
int Time2 = 10;

if(Time2 > Time)
{
 //Message box that tells you that the password has expired
}
else
{
//Random password generator code
}
```

I'm also using sql for the database, and i have a table user, where i stored the username and the password. But i haven't tried of accesing theme, because i wanted to get the code for the expiration password work first.
Also i have been investigating about my problem and i only found something Active Directory, but i don't think that solves my problem.
Any way i can solve this?

Comment: how do you check the passwords? by a table?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, to improve the likelihood of getting an answer consider clarifying the following: 1. where are the users stored? 2. how are you accessing them? 3. please explain what "but i can't make it work" means, exactly. For example, tell us what you tried. The community will need more information to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't auto make the password expire. The most common solution to this answer is to hold the Password Expiry date on the table where you keep your username and password.

During login process, check for valid login, if successful then check for password expiry. If the password is expired redirect to change password page instead of main form. And as tha password is updated don't forget to update the new expiry date as well.